# On-topic? "How to order on Amazon Japan without a credit card?"

Tags: discussion, scope

> While traveling in Japan, doing some or all of one's shopping for souvenirs or other items on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/) can be an attractive option over physical stores, for example for the large range of items for sale (especially from third-party Marketplace sellers who ship only to Japan), the discounts offered, or the time saved. However, some travelers may be unwilling or unable to use their credit card to order, for example because it simply does not work, or charges exorbitant exchange fees, or because they have exchanged their whole travel budget in cash. What other payment options are available?

This is a question I am considering asking and answering because I have found such alternative payments options useful myself when travelling, but which could certainly be considered off-topic as it is "primarily about Amazon" (see the comments [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10451/does-amazon-japan-deliver-to-hotels)). A credit card not working or charging hefty fees when used abroad is certainly an issue encountered mainly by travelers, but then again, so is receiving deliveries at hotels... Removing the "Amazon" part would certainly solve the problem, but would also make the question too broad if it means answers must apply universally to every online merchant. Maybe remove mentions of Amazon from the question but use it in an answer as an example?

Comment: I've never seen an online merchant accept anything except credit cards or bank transfers. The latter option is certainly extremely inconvenient. Maybe rephrase it as "Cheapest way of getting a prepaid credit card in Japan"?

Comment: @JonathanReez No, there is often a much more convenient option (cash at convenience stores), including on Amazon.

Comment: @JonathanReez: online merchants sometimes accept Paypal or similar services outside the US; some support Bitcoin; some support in-person cash payment at post offices or convenience stores (outside the US at least).  In fact I know of some merchants who charge extra for credit cards but not for these cash payments at a desk somewhere.

Comment: I use cards denominated variously in USD, GBP, and RUB and after I select which card, Amazon then asks which currency I want to pay in. There's always a **final price* shown for each currency. For lots of reasons I will purchase in the UK and pay in USD, other times I want to pay in Rubles, so check if that option is available to you. And yes, just post it and optionally explain why it's topical for this site

Comment: Can someone explain me what "bumped to the homepage" mean? I know community wikis, but this is new.

Comment: I am no longer interested in this question; mods please delete.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to be sure what is and what is not on topic here is to post and await developments.

I would agree quite likely too broad if omitting "Amazon" but there is no longer a "too localised" Close reason and Amazon seems so dominant "too localised" might not have been appropriate even when available.

There is a Travel connection - stronger IMO that for many questions here - so I would suggest well worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

IMO since what you actually want to answer is "yes, you can pay by cash in stores", you should rephrase the question to "**How do I pay by cash in stores when doing online shopping in Japan?**". This is perfectly on-topic (complex issue that travelers would have no idea how to solve) and isn't too focused on Amazon (since other stores probably accept it as well.

So, please, go ahead and make that post.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy an Amazon.jp point card at a Japanese convenience store for cash and then use that card to make a payment.

Alternately, you can have Amazon.jp ship to a convenience store or home and have Cash On Delivery as an option. Not all the marketplace vendors support this and it costs more. The cash card option is better.